# Determining a limit of an integral

Tags: integration, limits

let $f$ be a $2 \pi$ periodic function and k-differentiable. Show that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n^k \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) e^{inx}dx=0$$

I used integration by parts and found that:

$n^k \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) e^{inx}dx=  \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f^{(k)}(x) e^{inx}dx $

Comment: How did you find that? If it's true $f^{(k)}(x)$ is constant and it's not necessary to go till $\infty$, isn't it?

Comment: I did the first two integration by parts, and the terms without the integral cancels out

Answer (score 2):

The Riemann-Lebesgue measure gives you exactly what you need to finish the proof.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma

(Look in the "other versions" section.)

Comment: The integrand clearly goes to $0$,like you said, by the theorem,  but how do you know it goes to $0$ that much faster than $n^k \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Apply the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma to $f^{(k)}$.  I wasn't replacing the proof, merely finishing it.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I'm not the OP. I guess you meant Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma?

Comment: Fixed my comment.  Thanks.